# Undefined characters in string after reading file with fgetc()

Tags: c, fgetc

I'm trying to write a simple code in order to read the stdin then use it so I tried to type little program in order to put my stdin in a defined size table and it looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    int c , i = 0 ;
    char str[1024];

    while(c != EOF){
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        str[i]=c;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program with

```
$ test < file.json
```

I get:

```
{
    "num": 8
}�@/�
```

I can't explain the last four undefined characters. I'm guessing it's relative to the `fgetc()` pointer. I want to stop at the EOF.

I've looked everywhere, and I can't understand. I'm still learning C language, so my goal is to read the stdin which is a JSON file with the command

```
$ test < file.json
```

then use Jansson to extract and use the data, but my problem is reading the file with that command.

Comment: You start off by checking an uninitialized variable, and then you don't stop for EOF. You need to read the char, then stop if it's EOF, then use the char if it wasn't. Als you didn't null-terminate your buffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to null-terminate your string :

```
while (c != EOF) {
    c = fgetc(stdin);
    str[i]=c;
    i++;
}

str[i] = '\0';
```

And yes, you should initialize `c` prior to checking if it is `EOF`.

Comment: Sorta, mostly.  You didn't initialize `c` before the loop, so the first iteration could exit without reading anything.  There's a reason that `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` — or, for consistency with the question, `while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)` — is used to assign and control the loop; it avoids problems with uninitialized variables.  The question did correctly use `int c;` which is good.

Comment: @Haskell-newb: if you don't initialize `c`, it could have the value `EOF` when the program starts – in which case, you won't read anything.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

- `%s` expects a NUL-terminated string, but you did not add a NUL.
- You are checking the value of `c` before assigning a value to `c`.
- Your buffer can only hold 1023 characters plus a NUL, but you have no check for that.

Fixed:

```
int main() {
   size_t len = 0;
   size_t size = 1024;
   char* str = malloc(size);

   while (1) {
      int c = fgetc(stdin);
      if (c == EOF)
         break;

      str[len++] = c;

      if (len == size) {
         size = (double)size * 1.2;
         str = realloc(str, size);
      }
   }

   str[len] = 0;

   ...

   free(str);
   return 0;
}
```

(Doesn't check for `malloc` and `realloc` errors.)

Comment: thanks, i don't need a malloc because i know my stdin will use only 300 charaters max , and besides it was just a simple, my problem was with the undefined characters, and for the variable c , i didn't see that right away but i do get why i need to assign it , thank for your response

Comment: It's just as easy using malloc as adding a check, and far more useful. // And you are mistaken. Your program suffers from all three problems I mentioned. You simply only asked about the first one, and the other answer only covers the first one and gives a nonsense solution for the second one.